# The select command property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am working on a Windows forms project that connects to a Microsoft Access database, reads the the file, does some math and then provides some basic statistics back.  Right now I am teaching myself VB and I know the code below could be more efficient.  However, right now I am just trying to make it functional.

The program filters the data it needs via sql, and there are several sql statements.  I separated the code for each of the sql statements and into a subroutine so that I could call each one when the form loads and also when the user clicks a button to update.  The program works fine on the form load, however, when you click the update button you get the following error on the 'odaCalls.Fill' in subroutine Count(): "The select command property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I have searched on google and tried the suggestions found there but have not found a fix.

```
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

  'Count() Variables
  Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblcallLog"

  Dim strPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;" _
        & "Data Source=C:\callLogRev2_be.accdb"
  Dim odaCalls As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, strPath)
  Dim datCallCount As New DataTable
  Dim intCount As Integer = 0

  'LiveCalls() variables
  Dim strSQLLive As String = "SELECT * FROM tblcallLog WHERE callLive=True"
  Dim odaCallsLive As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLLive, strPath)
  Dim datCallLive As New DataTable
  Dim intCallLiveCount As Integer = 0
  Dim decCallLivePct As Decimal

  'TransferCalls() variables
  Dim strSQLTransfered As String = _
      "SELECT * FROM tblcallLog WHERE callName LIKE '% transfer %' OR callName LIKE 'transfer%'"
  Dim odaCallsTransfered As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLTransfered, strPath)
  Dim datCallTransfered As New DataTable
  Dim intCallTransfered As Integer = 0
  Dim decCallTranfered As Decimal

  'SingleStaffCall() Variables
  Dim strSQLSingleStaff As String = _
      "SELECT * FROM tblcallLog WHERE callName LIKE '% single %' OR callName LIKE 'single%'"
  Dim odaCallSingleStaff As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLSingleStaff, strPath)
  Dim datCallSingleStaff As New DataTable
  Dim intCallSingleStaff As Integer = 0
  Dim decCallSingleStaff As Decimal

  'SingleStaffCallsLive() Variables
  Dim strSQLSingleStaffLive As String = _
      "SELECT * FROM tblcallLog WHERE callName LIKE '% single %' OR callName LIKE 'single%' AND callLive=True"
  Dim odaCallSingleStaffLive As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLSingleStaffLive, strPath)
  Dim datCallSingleStaffLive As New DataTable
  Dim intCallSingleStaffLive As Integer = 0
  Dim decCallSingleStaffLive As Decimal

  'CallToday() Variables
  Dim strSQLToday As String = _
      "SELECT * FROM tblcallLog WHERE startDate = date()"
  Dim odaCallToday As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLToday, strPath)
  Dim datCallToday As New DataTable
  Dim intCallToday As New Integer

  'CallTodayLive() Variables
  Dim strSQLTodayLiveCalls As String = _
      "SELECT * FROM tblcallLog WHERE callLive=TRUE AND startDate = date()"
  Dim odaCallTodayLive As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLTodayLiveCalls, strPath)
  Dim datCallTodayLive As New DataTable
  Dim intCallTodayLive As New Integer
  Dim decCallTodayLive As New Decimal

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Count()
    LiveCalls()
    TransferCalls()
    SingleStaffCalls()
    SingleStaffCallsLive()
    CallToday()
    CallTodayLive()
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    'Checks the database for updates when user pushes the update button on the static data tab.
    Count()
    LiveCalls()
    TransferCalls()
    SingleStaffCalls()
    SingleStaffCallsLive()
    CallToday()
    CallTodayLive()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Count()
    'database connect and call count
    odaCalls.Fill(datCallCount)
    odaCalls.Dispose()

    intCount = datCallCount.Rows.Count

    lblTotalCallsData.Text = intCount.ToString
    lblTotalCallsData.Visible = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub LiveCalls()
    'determine number of live calls
    odaCallsLive.Fill(datCallLive)
    odaCallsLive.Dispose()

    intCallLiveCount = datCallLive.Rows.Count
    lblcallsLiveData.Text = intCallLiveCount.ToString
    lblcallsLiveData.Visible = True

    decCallLivePct = intCallLiveCount / intCount
    lblPctCallsLiveData.Text = decCallLivePct.ToString("P")
    lblPctCallsLiveData.Visible = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub TransferCalls()
    'determine the number of transfer calls

    odaCallsTransfered.Fill(datCallTransfered)
    odaCallsTransfered.Dispose()

    intCallTransfered = datCallTransfered.Rows.Count
    lblTotalTransferCallsData.Text = intCallTransfered.ToString
    lblTotalTransferCallsData.Visible = True

    decCallTranfered = intCallTransfered / intCount
    lblPctTransferCallsData.Text = decCallTranfered.ToString("P")
    lblPctTransferCallsData.Visible = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub SingleStaffCalls()
    'determine the number of single staff calls and percentage of total

    odaCallSingleStaff.Fill(datCallSingleStaff)
    odaCallSingleStaff.Dispose()

    intCallSingleStaff = datCallSingleStaff.Rows.Count
    lblTotalSingleStaffCallData.Text = intCallSingleStaff.ToString
    lblTotalSingleStaffCallData.Visible = True
    decCallSingleStaff = intCallSingleStaff / intCount
    lblPctSingleStaffCallsData.Text = decCallSingleStaff.ToString("P")
  End Sub

  Private Sub SingleStaffCallsLive()
    'determine the percentage of single staff calls taken live

    odaCallSingleStaffLive.Fill(datCallSingleStaffLive)
    odaCallSingleStaffLive.Dispose()

    intCallSingleStaffLive = datCallSingleStaffLive.Rows.Count
    decCallSingleStaffLive = intCallSingleStaffLive / intCount

    lblPctSingleStaffCallsLiveData.Visible = True
    lblPctSingleStaffCallsLiveData.Text = decCallSingleStaffLive.ToString("P")
  End Sub

  Private Sub CallToday()
    'determine values for todays date
    odaCallToday.Fill(datCallToday)
    odaCallToday.Dispose()

    intCallToday = datCallToday.Rows.Count
    lblTotalCallsTodayData.Text = intCallToday
    lblTotalCallsTodayData.Visible = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub CallTodayLive()
    'determine the number of live calls today
    odaCallTodayLive.Fill(datCallTodayLive)
    odaCallTodayLive.Dispose()

    intCallTodayLive = datCallTodayLive.Rows.Count
    lblCallsTodayLiveData.Text = intCallTodayLive.ToString
    lblCallsTodayLiveData.Visible = True

    'Statement to error correct so the database doesn't force the program to divide by zero
    Try
      decCallTodayLive = intCallTodayLive / intCallToday
    Catch Exception As DivideByZeroException
      lblPctCallsTodayLiveData.Text = "0.00%"
      lblPctCallsTodayLiveData.Visible = True
    Catch Exception As OverflowException
      decCallTodayLive = 0
    End Try

    lblPctCallsTodayLiveData.Text = decCallTodayLive.ToString("P")
    lblPctCallsTodayLiveData.Visible = True
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to post for your error.  Can you try trimming it down to just the relevant parts?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are disposing the dataadapters immediately after filling them.

This is why it works on form load, but not after. It would be better practice to create the and destroy the dataadapters in the methods where they are used instead of creating them on spec at the form level.

Comment: +1 it would also be a good idea to use the `Using` statement instead of calling Dispose. This can only be done if the OP does as you suggest.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions.

Comment: You are welcome. Please keep in mind that if an answer solved or help you solve your issue, that you should click the checkbox next to the answer to let future visitors to the question know that that answer worked for you.